# How to multiply the model coefficients by a number?

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

Hello I would like to scale the coefficients of my model. That's why I have prepared this little example.
I would like to multiply the coefficients of **MPG.city, MPG.highway, Horsepower** with the **"correction factor"**. Any Ideas how to multiply or correct the coefficients?

```
library(MASS)
data("Cars93")

Cars_new = Cars93[,c(4,5,6,7,8,13,14)]
fit<-lm(Price~.,data=Cars_new)

#model output should be list
fit<-list(fit)

#correction factor for MPG.city, MPG.highway,Horsepower
correction<-c(1.2,1.23,1.6)
```

**EDIT**
model output is a list!

[image: model output loos like this]

Answer (score 2):

You can select the coefficients by name

```
fit[[1]]$coefficients[c("MPG.city", "MPG.highway", "Horsepower")] <- 
   fit[[1]]$coefficients[c("MPG.city", "MPG.highway", "Horsepower")] * correction

#[[1]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = Price ~ ., data = Cars_new)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)    Min.Price    Max.Price     MPG.city  MPG.highway   Horsepower      RPM  
# -2.424e-02    5.010e-01    4.999e-01   -1.639e-04    1.029e-03   -1.504e-04   -1.293e-07
```